# jQuery UI Autocomplete Won't Set Control to Item Label

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

A jQuery UI Autocomplete widget can hold both a label and value for each item.

I was surprised to find that my textbox is set to the value and not the label as an item is selected. I could override this with the following code:

```
// ...
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#myEditBox').val(ui.item.label);
    $("#myHiddenField").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
},
// ...
```

That works fine when an item is selected. But the same problem occurs just when an item is just highlighted. After searching for some time, I was unable to see how to override that behavior.

Does anyone know how to set the textbox to the label of the item when that item is just highlighted?

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI? (so i can go to correct github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to handle to override the unintuitively named `focus` handler:

```
// ...
focus: function (event, ui) {
    $('#myEditBox').val(ui.item.label);
    $("#myHiddenField").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
},
// ...
```

Comment: well, you are "focusing" the item in the dropdown, :p